# Что учить desktop C#/.NET-разработчику?

Tags: c#

Я уже около 7 лет занимаюсь некоммерческой разработкой, хочу устроиться на работу на C#/.NET desktop-разработчика. Хочу уточнить, что мне нужно, а что точно не нужно учить именно для desktop, чтобы зря не тратить время. Вот как я понимаю:

**Точно нужно**

- C#/.NET, потоки, ООП, ООД, SOLID
- LINQ
- MVVM
- WPF, XAML
- Паттерны

**Не уверен**

- ASP.NET
- .Net Core
- MVC
- T-SQL, NoSQL, Oracle

**Точно не нужно**

- JS
- Angular
- Java
- F#

Comment: Есть мнение, что десктоп умирает.

Comment: Задайте корректно вопрос, в данном случае можно много давать ответов. но не один ответ не будет полным!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov отдельные отрасли может быть. Однако 3D графика не спешит умирать и она проще делается в настолках. Конечно, на WebAssembly недавно Doom 3 запустили, но пока не скоро туда все переберутся.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, есть мнение, то веб еще не созрел для большого количества софта. А любые технологии толстых клиентов так или иначе стремятся к десктопу. Истина где-то посередине.

Comment: Раз уж песнь про фреймворки завели, то ORM стоит добавить. А раз про него упомянули, то обязательно нужно вспомнить какую-нибудь трендовую РСУБД, вроде MS SQL Server (T-SQL), PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL), Oracle (PL/SQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Под desktop на данный момент в первую очередь понадобится:

- C# (общий функционал);
- потоки, ООП, ООД, SOLID;
- LINQ;
- MVVM;
- WinForms, WPF, UWP, XAML;
- Паттерны;
- Net Core;
- Базы данных (в т.ч. NoSQL).

Но, вообще за последние годы объём desktop разработки уменьшился на порядок. Программисты на том же C# в основном требуются под web.

> чтобы зря не тратить время

А, чтобы потратить время на подготовку с максимальной пользой, лучше обратиться как какой-нибудь сайт по трудоустройству и посмотреть требования к джуниору там и после  в соответствующем направлении работать.